# Fast Fourier Transform with negative amplitude

Tags: signal-processing, fft, amplitude, wavesurfer.js

Using wavesurfer to analyse bird songs data and getting negative amplitudes with the FFT analysis that I can not find the reason why.

I have been using wavesurfer for analysing my paper data on birds song. I open my data with the spectrogram and then in spectrum section is possible to find frequency and amplitude (using FFT analysis). My amplitude is negative but I can not find a way to justify that. I dont know why is that and I have significant results on my data, meaning that everything needs to be justified. The forum of the software does not work and there is literally no answer to my question on the internet. I have even emailed the creators asking for help. Find a screen attached to the windows.

[image: plot showing -60.1 dB amplitude]

Comment: It says “-60.1 dB”. dB are the units. I suggest you look up what those units mean. It will explain the minus. Hint: a magnitude is positive by definition, there exist no negative amplitudes!

Answer (score 1):

dB are on a logarithmic scale.  The log of a small enough positive FFT magnitude can be negative.
e.g. 20*log10(0.1) = -20

Answer (score 0):

We express values in dB in order to say something like: it's n times as large. A dB quantity is the log10 of a ratio, it is used to make a comparison between two measurements, for example output vs. input. Sometimes there is a single measurement compared with a fixed value. In that case we do not use the dB unit but some variants, e.g. if the reference is 1mW, we use dBm. The logarithmic scale facilitates calculations of attenuation and gain along a processing chain. A negative value indicates the ratio is less than 1, and the signal is attenuated (or less than the other), conversely a positive value indicates the signal is amplified (or greater than the other).

A dB (deci+Bel) is 0.1 B, so -60.1dB is -6.01B.

**Power ratio**

Originally the dB scale is related to power. Assuming the value is a power, you have to find the number which log10 is -6.01, a matter of taking the exponential of both sides:

log(x) = -6.01 (after conversion to B)
10^(log(x)) = 10^-6.01
x = 9.7e-07 ≈ 1/1,000,00

So your measurement is a power 1e6 times smaller than another power. Which one? It's not told, but it's likely the spectral line with the maximum value.

**Voltage ratio**

When dB relate to a ratio of voltages, the number is doubled for the same ratio. The reason is:

- It is assumed power is increased (or decreased) by managing to increase (decrease) some voltage. A change in the same proportion occurs for the current according to Ohm's law.
- Power is voltage x current, therefore to change the power in the ratio k, it's sufficient to change the voltage in the ratio sqrt(k). Log (sqrt(k)) = 1/2*log(k).

E.g.

- Power increase from 10W to 20W, a ratio of 2, is log(2) = 0.3B or 3dB.
- Voltage increase from 5V to 10V, also a ratio of 2 but 0.3B x 2 or 6dB.

**Root-power quantities vs. root-power quantities**

The rule actually separates power quantities (like power, energy or acoustic intensity) and root-power quantity (like voltage, sound pressure and electric field).